# Count Down Application giving Expected "]" error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I am building my first application for the iPhone and iPad, it is a simple application that counts down to the given month, day, hour, minute and second.

After fixing a couple of errors this is came across the following error:

> Expected "]"

Here's the code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation ViewController
-(void)updateLabel {
    NSCalendar *calender = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    int units = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *components = [calender components:units fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:destinationDate options:0 ];
    [dateLabel setText:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%c  %d%c  %d%c  %d%c  %d%c" , [components month], 'm' [components day], 'd' , [components hour], 'h' , [components minute], 'm' , [components second], 's' ]]; 
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    destinationDate = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1325153549] retain];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector (updateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: can you post the line of code where the exact error shown...

Comment: you probably missing any ] or adding another one, which line of code gives this error?

Comment: Seems that the line starting with `[dateLabel setText:` in `updateLabel` is missing the `]` You basically have `[dateLabel setText:[[...]];`

Answer (score 2):

```
    [dateLabel setText:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%c  %d%c  %d%c  %d%c  %d%c" , [components month], 'm' [components day], 'd' , [components hour], 'h' , [components minute], 'm' , [components second], 's' ]];
```

Unbalanced brackets?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose its this one?

```
[dateLabel setText:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%c  %d%c  %d%c  %d%c  %d%c" , [components month], 'm' [components day], 'd' , [components hour], 'h' , [components minute], 'm' , [components second], 's' ]];
```

You do open three [ in the first part before `NSString` but only close two of them in the end. This looks like you have once [ too much in the beginning and actually want

```
[dateLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%c  %d%c  %d%c  %d%c  %d%c" , [components month], 'm' [components day], 'd' , [components hour], 'h' , [components minute], 'm' , [components second], 's' ]];
```

Answer (score 0):

This line contains syntax errors:

```
[dateLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@  %d%@  %d%@  %d%@  %d%@" , [components month], @"m", [components day], @"d" , [components hour], @"h" , [components minute], @"m" , [components second], @"s"]];
```

You were missing a comma and had too many opening brackets before NSString.

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly is the error? I think it might be here:

```
[dateLabel setText:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%c  %d%c  %d%c  %d%c  %d%c" , [components month], 'm' [components day], 'd' , [components hour], 'h' , [components minute], 'm' , [components second], 's' ]];
```

seems like you forgot a comma here

```
'm' [components day]
```

Hope it helps

**Edit:**

And there's 1 "[" too many before NSString